# Using a different modem than the one provided by the ISP

Tags: router, passwords, modem, isp

I recently came into possession of two Frontier modems (modem/router). My dad likes the idea of using one of them because they can be switched off and on. However, our ISP is not Frontier; can we still use these routers even though we aren't using that ISP?

If this information helps, they were manufactured by NetGear and are approximately four years old (we also don't know their password(s)).

**Note:** This is not a cable router :)

Comment: cable or ADSL? ADSL should be a matter of setting the relevant bits. Cable, you may need to call the ISP.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ADSL, I made an edit to the post too :)

Comment: Call your ISP and ask

Comment: ah, ok. With stuff like this, its useful to know what sort of technology is at work. Unless the ISPs in question do wierd stuff with custom firmware, they should be happy to give you the settings for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases I believe this should not be an issue. As long as the modem is compatible with your current ISP, than you should be able to connect the modem through the coaxial cable.

However, the modems, MAC and S/N may be tied to the legacy ISP. So, it may not be a simple Plug n' Play went you connect the device. In short it should function as it is intended, however you may need to contact your current ISP and active the modem, and supply them with the correct MAC and S/N that was issued with the device.

Comment: Thanks. Also, if it is helpful, I made an edit to my original question :)